# Lock Using "Interlocked" vs lock Statement ("Monitor")

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, asynchronous

A followup question can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74475/lock-using-interlocked-vs-lock-statement-monitor-followup), based on this question and it's answer.

Considering:

1. `Interlocked.CompareExchange` generates a memory barrier,
2. Intended to be used with very fast operations (like generating an
   `id`),
3. `SpinWait` starts sleeping in milliseconds after 10 or so spins (and
   does some other smart stuff),

What are characteristics (pros & cons) of this code?

```
public class SpinMutex
{
    const long Locked = 1;
    const long Unlocked = 0;

    long _locked;

    public SpinMutex() { _locked = Unlocked; }

    public void Lock()
    {
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _locked, Locked, Unlocked) == Locked);
    }

    public bool Lock(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        return SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _locked, Locked, Unlocked) == Locked, millisecondsTimeout);
    }

    public bool Lock(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _locked, Locked, Unlocked) == Locked, timeout);
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _locked, Unlocked);
    }
}
```

And some extra points to consider:

- Does it help if `SpinMutex` be defined as `struct` instead of a
  `class` (I'm aware there would be hurdles with say `readonly` fields
  of `struct` type and the like)?
- Should `Interlocked.CompareExchange` be used in `Unlock` too, instead of
  `Interlocked.Exchange` to ensure generating of a memory barrier? Or
  `Interlocked.Exchange` generates a memory barrier itself? Is a memory barrier needed at all at `Unlock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost I think your implementation is broken: [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the *original* value at the location. So in your lock methods you should spin until the original value was `Unlocked` and not `Locked`.

As for your first question: Besides that "better" is a very vague term - no I don't think making it a `struct` is better for the simple reason that you have a mutable structure (it can change it's own state between locked and unlocked) and mutable `structs` are generally best to be avoided - the value semantics of it can trip you up pretty quick.

For your second question: As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355%28VS.85%29.aspx) all Interlocked methods make use of the appropriate barriers.

In general:

1. I would check that the lock was actually locked in `Unlock` (and throw if it wasn't) - unlocking an already unlocked lock indicates a potentially serious bug (lock/unlock should always be in matching pairs).
2. I'd consider implementing `IDisposable` and check that the lock is not locked when being disposed. Any object owning a lock instance should then dispose of it - this adds another check that the locking/unlocking is done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

- I would not use a `long` for `_locked`. You don't need such a big variable. On some 32 bit architectures atomically exchanging a value larger than 32 bits may incur a significant performance hit.
- Rename your `bool` returning `Lock` methods to `TryLock`. A method called `Lock` should either succeed or throw an exception.